# Splitting Kafka Message Line by line in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I want to read a message from Kafka topic in my Spark Structured Streaming job into a data frame. but I am getting entire message in one offset so in data frame only this message is coming into one row instead of multiple rows. (in my case it is 3 rows)

When I print this message I am getting below output:

[image]

The message "Text1", "Text2" and "Text3" I want in 3 rows in data frame so that I can process further.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a *user defined function* (UDF) to convert the message string into a sequence of strings, and then apply the *explode* function on that column, to create a new row for each element in the sequence:

As illustrated below (in scala, same principle applies to pyspark):

```
case class KafkaMessage(offset: Long, message: String)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

val df = sc.parallelize(List(KafkaMessage(1000, "Text1\nText2\nText3"))).toDF()

val splitString = udf { s: String => s.split('\n') }

df.withColumn("splitMsg", explode(splitString($"message")))
  .select("offset", "splitMsg")
  .show()
```

this will yield the following output:

```
+------+--------+
|offset|splitMsg|
+------+--------+
|  1000|   Text1|
|  1000|   Text2|
|  1000|   Text3|
+------+--------+
```